# Отображение картинки при подгрузке файла (load)

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, javascript

Ребята, скажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы пока подгружается файл, показывалась картинка (loader), а после загрузки она убиралась?  Типа как .ajaxStart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/), [.ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/), [.ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/)

```
$(function() {
    var $loader = $('#loader');
    $.ajaxSetup({
        start: function() { $loader.show(); },
        complete: function() { $loader.hide(); } // в случае успеха/ошибки
    });
});
```

Я в своем [проекте](https://github.com/neoascetic/openstreetreview) еще нечто вроде простейшего стека делал на основе списка, чтобы `loader` отображался, пока есть хоть один запрос (в бэкграунде, мол, работаю):

```
var ajax_queue = [],
    $ajax_spinner = $('#ajax_spinner');

$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 20000, // для кроссдоменных
    beforeSend: function(XHR) {
        ajax_queue.push(XHR);
        $ajax_spinner.show();
    },
    complete: function() {
        ajax_queue.pop();
        $ajax_spinner.toggle(!!ajax_queue.length); // must be Boolean!
    }
});
```

Пользуйтесь!

Comment: Только надо добавить, что методы эти работают только для **$.ajax()**. Если используется **$.post()** или **$.get()**, то параметры не отработают.

Comment: Только что попробовал - для `.get()` все замечательно работает

Comment: Хм.. Возможно, что в новых версиях были изменения. Раньше пробовал - не прокатывал. Ну, тем лучше.

Comment: @zhekonya вы о чем? `Timeout` чаще всего необходим для кроссбраузерных запросов. В ином случае браузер сам разруливает, когда случилась ошибка

Comment: все сделал! спасибо всем!